# How to Learn/Create a Database iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I have a rather simple idea for an iPhone app. What I need to accomplish:

- Allow login of users (which means I'll have to store usernames, passwords, and other account info).
- Allow users to submit strings that other users can view.
- Attributes attached to each string that must be tracked (i.e. "votes, views, comments, etc.).

As such, I assume I'll need to start learning about databases and working between a server and client. I've gotten my feet wet in OSX/iOS programming (specifically Objective-C) before. I want to learn how one can accomplish a data-based application and the needs I listed above.

I've done some light research and discovered something called SQLite (free and open-source is always good). Is this the right path to achieve what I want to do? I'm a total "noob" when it comes to this field of server/client/data "stuff".

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Removed Objective-C tag as no code is shown and removed Xcode tag as the question is not about Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLLite is more like a local database. Really, the database that you will use is unimportant. It sounds like a project with webservices. Inside your webservices, you might connect to a Microsoft SQL Server or anything you want.

I think you should study how to setup a webservice that can be accessed in your code. Webservices is not an Objective-C topic, it applies to any platform. Your project is more like a web development project.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The idea I have could ultimately be implemented into a website, too. How should I go about learning about webservices and the best way to implement it into an iPhone app (or implementing it in general)?

Comment: Shane. You could use SOAP Web Services. Trust me, connecting your phone via web services is very simple. Your 90% work is in the server. SOAP is platform independent, you should buy a book for it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Platform independent sounds good just in-case I ever decide to produce a website version of my "idea". I've never heard of SOAP. Is it secure?

Comment: SOAP is a very and very popular technology. However, there are many and many more alternatives. I suggest you just forget you have an iPhone, but focus more on writing a server. You can use your PC to connect to the web services. Once you know your server is ready, then think how to bind data from your server to iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Should I use SOAP with Java for all the behind-the-scenes work, and use Javascript and HTML5 to implement it for the end-user? I was thinking of using SOAP with Java for the server.

Comment: It really doesn't matter. Does it? Just use whatever you think you are most confident. I used C# myself, but Java is more enough. Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can save user's credentials in [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH203-TP1).

@Kinderchocolate is right about introducing database into your project.

Answer (score 0):

It hears about a app which need transmitting data among clients.It means your need  server database and local database.

For server database,I recommend you to use Parse.Parse is a platform which provide a convenient way to use their server database with Objective-c in your app.This tool will save many times and energy(it's not necessary to learn PHP,Apache,Mysql).Parse is not free of course,but it has a free period and enough for you to examine your idea. 
Here's [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)!.

For local database,I recommend you to use Core Data,Which is provided by XCode.Core data is so strong to meet your need.You can find a way to use Core Data in many books.

Answer (score -1):

Go try Firebase for database in the cloud. (On the server). In Swift 4 there is complete support for Firebase and SQLite